# How to transform a set of scores into a normal distribution score?

Tags: normal-distribution, transformation, linear-transformations

I have a set of people with scores. Let's say:
Person1: 18
Person2: 1,879
Person3: 873
Person4: 1M
...
Person2M: 9,387

I would like to give each of these, a 0-100 Score, that is distribution in a normal distribution. Meaning most people will get 50, and very few people will get above 97 and less than 3, etc.. 
How can I do this?

Comment: What's 1m? What's 2M?

Comment: It was just an example, but it's just 1,000,000

Comment: Person2M just means i have scores for millions of people